RuntimeError: `tf.data.Dataset` only supports Python-style iteration in eager mode or within tf.function
Here is my Tensor Flow Code illustrating problem with tf.data.Dataset iteration in eager mode

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--path', help='Path of the video you want to test on.', default=0)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    MINSIZE = 20
    THRESHOLD = [0.6, 0.7, 0.7]
    FACTOR = 0.709
    IMAGE_SIZE = 182
    INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE = 160
    CLASSIFIER_PATH = 'Models/facemodel.pkl'
    FAKE_PATH = 'liveness.h5'
    VIDEO_PATH = args.path
    FACENET_MODEL_PATH = 'Models/20180402-114759.pb'

    # Load The Custom Classifier
 with open(CLASSIFIER_PATH, 'rb') as file:
 model, class_names = pickle.load(file)
    
    
 modelfake = load_model(FAKE_PATH)
print("Custom Classifier, Successfully loaded")

 with tf.Graph().as_default():

 # Cai dat GPU neu co
 gpu_options = tf.compat.v1.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.6)
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options, log_device_placement=False))
        
 with sess.as_default():

 # Load the model
print('Loading feature extraction model')      facenet.load_model(FACENET_MODEL_PATH)
 # Get input and output tensors
images_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
 embeddings = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("embeddings:0")
 phase_train_placeholder = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("phase_train:0")
  embedding_size = embeddings.get_shape()[1]

 pnet, rnet, onet = align.detect_face.create_mtcnn(sess, "src/align")

 people_detected = set()
 person_detected = collections.Counter()

 cap  = VideoStream(src=0).start()
 number_of_frame=0
 count = 0
                     
 while (True):
   frame = cap.read()
   frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
                    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
                    count += 1
                    bounding_boxes, _ = align.detect_face.detect_face(frame, MINSIZE, pnet, rnet, onet, THRESHOLD, FACTOR)

  faces_found = bounding_boxes.shape[0]

 if number_of_frame>=5:
                        
 playsoundfunc([x for x in name_list if x[0]==int(name)][0])
  number_of_frame=0

  if faces_found > 1:

  cv2.putText(frame, "Only one face", (0, 100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1, (255, 255, 255), thickness=1, lineType=2)
                    elif faces_found > 0:
                        
 det = bounding_boxes[:, 0:4]
bb = np.zeros((faces_found, 4), dtype=np.int32)
                        cv2.imwrite("frame%s.jpg" % 1, frame )
                      
 for i in range(faces_found):           
                            
  bb[i][0] = det[i][0]
  bb[i][1] = det[i][1]
  bb[i][2] = det[i][2]
  bb[i][3] = det[i][3]
 print(bb[i][3]-bb[i][1])
                            print(frame.shape[0])
 print((bb[i][3]-bb[i][1])/frame.shape[0])
if (bb[i][3]-bb[i][1])/frame.shape[0]>0.25:
                                

  cropped = frame[bb[i][1]:bb[i][3], bb[i][0]:bb[i][2], :]
                                
 scaled = cv2.resize(cropped, (INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE),
                                                    interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
                                scaled = facenet.prewhiten(scaled)
                                scaled_reshape = scaled.reshape(-1, INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, INPUT_IMAGE_SIZE, 3)
                                feed_dict = {images_placeholder: scaled_reshape, phase_train_placeholder: False}
                                emb_array = sess.run(embeddings, feed_dict=feed_dict)
                                
  face = cv2.resize(cropped, (32, 32))
  face = face.astype("float") / 255.0
  face = img_to_array(face)
                                
  face = np.expand_dims(face, axis=0)

   preds = modelfake.predict(face)[0]
   predictions = model.predict_proba(emb_array)                            
                                best_class_indices = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
                                print(best_class_indices)
                                best_class_probabilities = predictions[
                                    np.arange(len(best_class_indices)), best_class_indices]
                                best_name = class_names[best_class_indices[0]]
                                print("Name: {}, Probability: {}".format(best_name, best_class_probabilities[0]))

enter image description here
I have created a model to identify antispoofing using keras and want to apply it to my face recognition program using face net and mtcnn but there is a problem like this
